# identifying left recursion in antlr4

Tags: antlr4

A grammar (copied from its manual) reports the following left recursions when
I un-commented the following production: casting_type->constant_primary

```
error(119): The following sets of rules are mutually left-recursive [primary, method_call_root, method_call, cast]
  and [casting_type, constant_cast, cast, constant_primary, constant_function_call, function_subroutine_call, primary]
  and [subroutine_call, function_subroutine_call, constant_function_call, constant_primary, method_call, method_call_root, casting_type, primary, constant_cast, cast]
```

The above error report has 3 sets of rules. The third set has 2 left-recursions in it:

1. casting_type,constant_primary,constant_cast,casting_type
2. casting_type,constant_primary,constant_function_call,function_subroutine_call,subroutine_call,method_call,method_call_root,primary,cast,casting_type

Since this error was reported after I un-commented one production, I
think it is reasonable to expect to see at least its names in each set (casting_type,constant_primary). Clearly the first set
lacks both these names, so it cannot contain a recursion. And the second set (I cannot give the full
grammar here because it is too long) has recursion-1 and some extra names
which seem not relevant.

My question is: why is Antlr printing the first and the second sets of rules?
Is this a bug in antlr (I tried 4.6 and 4.7, same result), or is this hinting at a problem that I am missing something in these sets?

I saw a similar post [elsewhere](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/il-antlr-interest/6uWBq9czEo8), where the reported names did not indicate a recursion, but on deeper analysis recursion was found somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

Probably nobody can really answer your question, not even the authors of ANTLR. To me it looks like you get follow-up errors which make not much sense, because a real error made analysis impossible (or at least can lead to wrong conclusions). Of course there can also be a bug in ANTLR, but I recommend to focus on one of the sets and fix that (if you can see what makes them mutually left recursive). Maybe the other errors disappear then or you have to analyze again.

Comment: Yes, thats what I have done. I took the set that made most sense, and fixed that, and then the other sets vanished. Looks like a bug in antlr, it should be a simple case of cycle detection among the rules.